# How to displayHelp in WizardPage dialog rather than the Workbench

Tags: java, eclipse, jface, wizard

In a NewWizard, implemented using the Eclipse extension point "org.eclipse.ui.newWizards", when the org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage opens I would like the help area, on the right hand side, to be shown immediately without having to press the (?) help button.

I call the following code at the end of the WizardPage.createControl(Composite parent), but the help opens in the workbench behind the wizard dialog. I would like it to open the help on the right hand side of the wizard.

```
private void sethelp() {
    postSetFocus(this.getControl());
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(this.getControl(), STR_CONTEXT );
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().displayDynamicHelp();
}

private void postSetFocus(final Control control) {
    Display display = control.getDisplay();
    if (display != null) {
        display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                control.setFocus();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm fairly confident my help context is correct. Once the wizardpage is open if I click the (?) button manually the help does open along the right hand side of the wizard. But I want it to happen programmatically.

Am I missing something about PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem()?

Thanks for any help (no pun intended).

Comment: Try doing the `displayDynamicHelp` in the asyncExec Runnable after the `setFocus`.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work; still not displayed in the wizard dialog. Its as though I'm not getting the correct activeShell, but instead getting the normal workbench. I tried this:
  IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
  window.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().displayDynamicHelp();
but that has same behaviour.